# How do I tell tensorflow to ignore some calculations?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have two cases where I want to perform two different calculations based on some condition, currently I am using tf.cond to switch between the two conditions, however I have noticed that Tensorflow calculates both the cases and then simply uses the condition to determine which one to return. This is basically what my code looks like:

```
Tensor_1 = #Lots of complex calculations
Tensor_2 = tf.eye(dimensions)
Result = tf.cond( my_condition, lambda: Tensor_1, lambda: Tensor_2 )
```

My problem is that one of these calculations is a lot slower than the other but a lot rarer too, how do I go about telling Tensorflow not to perform the calculations unless a condition is satisfied?

I have also tried tf.case and tf.switch_case, both appear to have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

From tensorflows documentation:
"Warning: Any Tensors or Operations created outside of true_fn and false_fn will be executed regardless of which branch is selected at runtime."

You do not have any true_fn or false_fn which does any operations, hence there's nothing to "ignore". The tensors has to be evaluated first since they are input arguments to the functions in tf.cond. Move the "Lots of complex calculations" to a separate function and then call that function, so something like this:

```
Tensor_1 = #Input to lots of complex calculations
Result = tf.cond( my_condition, lambda: complex_calculations(Tensor_1), function_returning_eye )
```

I have also discovered that putting a python for loop inside the functions breaks this behaviour and forces tensorflow to evaluate that branch no matter the condition.